# MVC action works only at localhost

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

Windows 2012, IIS 8, ASP MVC, VS 2013, .NET 4.5.

I have AJAX with jEditable plugin in View, to send POST query to my controller action:

```
    $('.edit').editable('/Calendar/Update', {
        type: 'textarea',
        select: true,
        submit: 'OK',
        cancel: 'cancel',
    });
```

And I have Update action in Controller:

```
  public string Update (DateTime datetime, string value, string id)
    {
        var updateQuery = (from i in db.tbl_Calendars
                          where i.date == datetime
                          select i).FirstOrDefault();

       ...


        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return value;
    }
```

The problem is, I launch project at dev environment at localhost and it works perfectly well, but when I deploy it to production public server, AJAX call to /Calendar/Update shows me 404 error. I've searhed over all Internet, copied all used libraries in /bin, edited wildcard mappings, used runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests. No result.

Comment: What if you use the absolute path of the production server in your code just to verify that it hits then?

Comment: Already used that, same result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use url action helper for ajax action url

```
$('.edit').editable('@Url.Action("Update", "Calendar")', {
        type: 'textarea',
        select: true,
        submit: 'OK',
        cancel: 'cancel',
    });
```